# Template/Tips for Photo/Artwork viewing only App in iOS

Tags: ios, photo-gallery

First, I must say have never programmed in iOS, I am only familiar with Matlab & Mathematica.

I would like to create an App to show my artwork & photography. A "view only" app. yet.

Any suggestion on existing templates or place to start ?

Many thanks for your attention & any help you could provide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google for iPhone tutorials.  There are undoubtedly some opensource photoviewer apps out there.  Apple has a few takes in their developer examples.  But here's the thing:  You are going to need a lot more background in iOS basics to get what you want completed.  You really need to be looking at beginner's iPhone tutorials, of which the web is flooded with them.  Google.

Comment: Thank You. I believe I/We learn best while directly implementing knowledge on actual problem we are trying to solve. In this case I would start by looking at a template/example and look for knowledge as I go through. Even if it start at line 1 of the example as it probably will. This is why I allow myself this question, I know about Google !